# PuPHPet Error: install php7.0-mysqlnd' returned 100

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, puphpet

I got a problem running a PuPHPet Box, the PHP Service does not start, I get the following error after `vagrant up`:

`Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install php7.0-mysqlnd' returned 100: Reading package lists...`

After This, the php service fails to start:

```
==>  Reading state information...
==>  The following NEW packages will be installed:
==>    php7.0-mysql
==>  0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 109 not upgraded.
==>  Need to get 124 kB of archives.
==>  After this operation, 486 kB of additional disk space will be used.
==>  Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 php7.0-mysql amd64 7.0.33-20+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [124 kB]
==>  Fetched 124 kB in 0s (570 kB/s)
==>  Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-mysql.
(Reading database ... 54197 files and directories currently installed.)
==>  Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-mysql_7.0.33-20+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
==>  Unpacking php7.0-mysql (7.0.33-20+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
==>  Processing triggers for php7.0-fpm (7.0.33-20+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
==>  Job for php7.0-fpm.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status php7.0-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The machine is starting and I can ssh into it, manually installing php also fails.

I am using Virtual Box on Windows 10 and Git Bash. I tried all available PHP-Versions (7.0, 7.1, 7.2), tried several times provisioning, destroying the machine, going through the creation process on [PuPHPet.com](https://puphpet.com). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar issue the past couple of days. After SSHing into the box and running `journalctl -u php7.0-fpm` I got this log:

```
Feb 14 09:53:47 vagrant systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager...
Feb 14 09:53:47 vagrant update-alternatives[10343]: update-alternatives: error: alternative path /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock doesn't exist
Feb 14 09:53:47 vagrant systemd[1]: php7.0-fpm.service: PID file /run/php/php7.0-fpm.pid not readable (yet?) after start-post: No such file or directory
Feb 14 09:55:17 vagrant systemd[1]: php7.0-fpm.service: Start-post operation timed out. Stopping.
Feb 14 09:55:17 vagrant systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
Feb 14 09:55:17 vagrant systemd[1]: php7.0-fpm.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 14 09:55:17 vagrant systemd[1]: php7.0-fpm.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Feb 14 09:55:22 vagrant systemd[1]: Stopped The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
```

Turns out the PID file path is wrong.

You can update the PID file `$pid_file` variable within the params.pp. 
File path:`puphpet/puppet/modules/puphpet/manifests/php/params.pp`

Updating this value to `run/php/php7.0-fpm.pid` then destroying and running `vagrant up` fixed this issue for me.

There's also a pull request within the puphpet repo with this change: https://github.com/AOEpeople/puppet-puphpet/commit/e3b50ce72b922c2649ac82979b02edfd4e3b8c0a

Comment: Hi @Matthew, this is the solution, thank you very much. At first I tried to set the path like in the merge request [link]https://github.com/AOEpeople/puppet-puphpet/commit/e3b50ce72b922c2649ac82979b02edfd4e3b8c0a but I had to do it manually, like your answer states. Working now.

Comment: @roxxor No problem. Yes I had to manually set it too. Using `${version_match}` did not work for me either.